# Are there studies about religious belief similar to the ones about superstition among animals?

Tags: reference-request, behaviorism

In [this question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/774/2516) they talk about how animals can develop rituals that they thing have some influence in a particular outcome, when in reality there isn't a real connection whatsoever between the performed ritual and the reward they expect as an outcome.

So, I'm curious about whether there are similar studies involving religion.

**Update**

Let's say we have the soccer players that make the sign of the cross over them before the match begins, and the pigeon that make a circled counter-clockwise before the food is dropped, I'm not sure if I can draw a line separating superstition from religion in that case.

Comment: Not sure I follow ... are you asking about evidence of religious beliefs in animals?

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I've updated the question with an example, thanks.

Comment: There are countless thousands of superstitions that arise out of people trying to project/protect illusion of control over the chaotic world. Higher religions typically arise out of mystical experiences, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_helmet  I'm sure such experiences are neither available to animals nor can be fully interpreted by them

Comment: I believe the question is whether religious behaviors in humans, like the soccer play making a cross before the match, can be explained in the same way as animals developing rituals.

Comment: @Josh I agree, but until an edit is made to the question, it risks being closed as being "unclear"